# For loop issue in class

Tags: class, sobject, list, update, loop

I have to get IDs of Call custom object from Incident Transaction custom object and run a for loop on call feeding the list. Can someone help me here?

```
   List<SObject> myCalls = [SELECT Call_abv__c FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c];

   List<Call2_vod__c> Call= new List<Call2_vod__c>();

    for(Call2_vod__c cl:myCalls)
    {   

    }
```

Getting below error:

> Compile Error: Loop variable must be of type SObject at line

Comment: why don't you use `List` of type `Incident_Transaction_abv__c` for the query result?

Comment: Your loop variable `cl` is of type `Call2_vod__c` while the structure `myCalls` is of type `SObject`. Your question is a bit unclear, though.

Comment: I have to fetch Call IDs from Incident transaction then do some update operation on the calls. @Mahmood

Comment: @highfive The result would be same.

Comment: You're looping Incident_Transaction_abv__c records with Call2_vod__c object! What are you trying to do?

Comment: I hope you have tried using the same type for the `List` as well as in `for` loop, coz as per your code it's not

Comment: I need to update X field on Call object if the Call's ID is present in INcident Transaction's Y field (which is a call ID reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to typecast List of SObjects to List of relevant object. So your code should look like -

```
   List<SObject> myCalls = [SELECT Call_abv__c FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c];
   List <Incident_Transaction_abv__c> myCallsInc = (List <Incident_Transaction_abv__c>) myCalls;
   List<Call2_vod__c> Call= new List<Call2_vod__c>();
   for(Incident_Transaction_abv__c ita : myCallsInc )
    {   

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Amit! I was failing here. But update needs to be done on Calls. I need for loop for calls.

Answer (score 1):

myCalls is of type `List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c>`. You can't iterate over a more specific type than a less specific type without casting. You need to make the loop variable type and the list type agree with each other.